# LIKE button - won't use new meta description

Tags: button, facebook-like, meta-tags, reset

I've tried to change the text to the link that appears on FB, when I press the LIKE button on my webpage. (Using meta)

But something weard is happening...
My new description appears with commentfield, when I press the LIKE button on my webpage.
But when the link appears on FB it's an OLD text, that I haven't used in a while - and it's no where in my HTML.

FB must remember this, somehow, and use it.
I don't know how to reset this..

I can't post my code, because stackoverflow won't show it.... 
But I've used the open tag and the prefix=og. So there's nothing wrong with my meta.
Besides... why does it remember an old text that doesn't exist anymore?

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 1):

The Debugger does work but you must close the browser clear chance or use a different browser before its effects will work.

Answer (score 0):

Put your link into the Debug tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

This will reset the data and facebook will start to use the updated text.